# Easiest Google Maps API (javascript/PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I have an array of latitudes/longitudes and Descriptions that I want to display on a Google Map.

Does anyone know of an API (or even better a tutorial) that describes a good way to accomplish this or something similar using PHP and/or Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [static maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) is the simplest to use. You can use PHP and cURL to grab the map you need with the data you have (latitude/longitude).

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Google labss: Google fusion tables: then make those two lat/lon fields the "location"

google for the term: google fusion table map